# Properly "stamp" an image on a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I properly "attach" an image on a GameObject?

Comment: hi Jean, if you're talking a 3D game, I'm guessing what you're looking for is called a **decal** in game engineering.  Just google "Unity add decal" for 1000s of tutorials and discussions.  (Used for example when you add "bullet holes to walls" or "mud spatters to the vehicle".)  If you mean how to make a 2D game sprite, just click ***Game Object, 2D, Sprite***. couldn't be easier.  no need to attach anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what you want the image for, there are different ways to have an object render as an image.

Assuming you're trying to make a 2D game, it sounds like what you are looking for is the [Sprite Renderer](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sprite-renderer).

The GUI texture you tried to use is [deprecated](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUITexture.html) and was part of an old system for menus and UI elements. If a UI is what you're after, take look at [UI Image](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-image?playlist=17111).

Comment: An excellent answer, in the future look for people asking duplicates of this and close those new questions, marking this one as the original.